# How to detect charset encoding with php icu extensions?

Tags: php, character-encoding, detection, icu

ICU has functions to detect charset encodings, [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection/) and PHP also has ICU extension, [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)  but how to use php icu extension to do the charset detection? I can not find anything related to this part on php's doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a [new feature request](https://bugs.php.net/report.php?package=intl) for the PHP extension, or an opportunity to [contribute it yourself](https://github.com/cataphract/PECL-intl).